# How to integrate the add function from html to angular js?

Tags: angularjs, integration

I have my [add](/questions/tagged/add) button in my [index.html](/questions/tagged/index.html) and I need to create a function in [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) 
controller. The [select](/questions/tagged/select) option in the code below needs to get the data from another table.  All I need is when the [tag:add button] is clicked, it will be temporarily be added in the [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) controller.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="control-label">Board Member</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="Board" ng-init="">
                                                <option value=""> -- Select --</option>            
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: elaborate your question ..

Answer (score 0):

in the ng-click directive name your function like so ng-click="add()".

then in your controller define the add function:

```
$scope.add = function(){
  //whatever your function needs to do
}
```